# Responsive design for iphone landscape and portrait

Tags: ios, css, responsive-design, viewport

I've been trying to test my code on my iphone 4, I am running iOS6.

Everything looks fine and dandy inside of the iphone when in portrait mode, however when I switch to landscape everything is zoomed in! Any suggestions? My viewport code is below along with the css condition.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.5, user-scalable=0" />

@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    #sidebar {
        width:38px;
    }
    .menuhide {
        display:none;
    }
    .menushow {
        display:inline;
    }
    #mainframe {
        margin-left:38px;
    }
}
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe using this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=0">
```